# How to access objects in other classes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to access an object `buttonReturn` from another class `Return` so I can call a method on it.

I want to hide `buttonReturn` on the first page by placing it out of view (`x=-100`), and then use the next page button to place the return button in view.

I tried using `Return.buttonReturn.place(x=0, y=0)` but it gave me `AttributeError: type object 'Return' has no attribute 'buttonReturn'`

Below is the program as much as I could reduce it

```
import tkinter as tk
PreviousPage = None


class Controller(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (FirstPage, SecondPage, Return):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.geometry("200x100")
        self.show_frame(FirstPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Return(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        buttonReturn = tk.Button(text="return", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PreviousPage))
        buttonReturn.place(x=-100, y=0)


class FirstPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="first page")
        label.place(x=0, y=50)

        buttonA = tk.Button(self, text="next page", command=lambda: nextPage())
        buttonA.place(x=70, y=0)

        def nextPage():
            global PreviousPage
            PreviousPage = FirstPage
            Return.buttonReturn.place(x=0, y=0) #problematic code
            controller.show_frame(SecondPage)


class SecondPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="second page")
        label.place(x=0, y=50)


app = Controller()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create a Return object to call so you are just calling the class. 
To get what you want to happen change:

```
Return.buttonReturn.place(x=0, y=0)
```

to

```
returnbutton = Return(parent, controller)
returnbutton.buttonReturn.place(x=0, y=0)
```

And in the Return class add self in front of the buttonReturn Statements:

```
self.buttonReturn = tk.Button(text="return", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PreviousPage))
self.buttonReturn.place(x=-100, y=0)
```